# unique records in multidimensional on key basis

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have this array and I want to get only unique records based on a key `user_to`

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": {
    "unread_chat": 1,
    "chatlist": [
      {
        "id": 769,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 754,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": true,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 753,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": true,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 749,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 748,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 746,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 741,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": true,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 740,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": true,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 739,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": true,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 738,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 735,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 733,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": true,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 732,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": true,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 729,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": true,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 727,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 39,
        "chats": "hello",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 17:36:13",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 726,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 725,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": true,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 679,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 678,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 677,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the code I have used.

```
    $messages = UserAdvertiserMessages::where(['user_id' => $user_id])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->skip($offset * $limit)
            ->take($limit)
            ->get();
```

If I used `->unique('user_to')` then I get proper results but it added index. So the code for get proper results

```
$messages = UserAdvertiserMessages::where(['user_id' => $user_id])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->skip($offset * $limit)
        ->take($limit)
        ->get()->unique('user_to');
```

Output

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": {
    "unread_chat": 1,
    "chatlist": {
      "0": {
        "id": 769,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 210,
        "chats": "There?",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 23:31:37",
        "online": false,
        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      "1": {
        "id": 754,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 226,
        "chats": "yes",
        "is_read": true,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 22:17:21",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      },
      "14": {
        "id": 727,
        "user_id": 211,
        "user_to": 39,
        "chats": "hello",
        "is_read": false,
        "created_at": "2018-07-21 17:36:13",
        "online": false,

        "unread_msg": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your excerpt is JSON, doesn't really tell us what $messages contains or where it's used.  I can assume the chatlist index represents $messages.  Your code should work fine.

Comment: Did you try: `['user_id' => $user_id, 'user_to' => $user_to]`?

Comment: Try `$messages->values()->all();`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone : as you can see user_to can be multiple and I didn't have their ids.

Answer (score 0):

try with this **distinct()**

```
$messages = UserAdvertiserMessages::where(['user_id' => $user_id])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->skip($offset * $limit)
            ->take($limit)
            ->get()->distinct('user_to');
```